# US vs Indian Patent System differences

Tags: claims, filing, foreign, india

We may be filing for a patent in India, and while our attorneys will be doing the heavy lifting, I was just curious about what major differences there are in the patent system between there and the United States.

I'm curious about general differences, but specifically,

- Is the patent term 20 years in India too?
- Any differences in claims language or the breadth of claims allowed?
- Are prophetic experiments allowed in place of actual experiments?
- Are biotech patents allowed to patent the gene itself or merely a method that uses / synthesizes the gene?

In case it matters, this is a biotech patent about a transgenic organism.

Comment: @curious_cat Thanks for your edits--much appreciated. I've gone ahead and reopened this for you. The second question ("differences in claims language") could be made a little more specific with an example of what sort of thing you're talking about, but I think this should be specific enough to get you an answer worthy of fulfilling a surface-level curiosity, if not one suitable to base a patent off of.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the patent term 20 years in India too?

Yes, the patent term is 20 years from filing date of non-provisional or PCT application.

> Any differences in claims language or the breadth of claims allowed?

No much difference can be expected as most of the claims in US and IN are same.

> Are prophetic experiments allowed in place of actual experiments?

if you are trying to explain an alternate embodiment possible the prophetic experiments are allowed but for patenting a claim actual experimental date is required.

> Are biotech patents allowed to patent the gene itself or merely a method that uses / synthesizes the gene?

No, isolated genes are not patentable but the process of synthesis is patentable.